# How to find XPath of a url of an image?

Tags: wordpress, xpath

I'm trying to map a XML to import to Wordpress using the WP All Import plugin, but I got stuck after tried several ways to get the "scr" of this image:

```
<content type="html">

<div align="center" class="post-cover">

  <img src="IMG.jpg"/>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

</div> 
</content>
```

I Tried `{content[1]/div[1]/img/@src}` and `{content[1]/div/img/@src}`, but no success.

The only path that indeed worked somehow was `{content[@type = "html"]}` and `{content[1]}` that showed all the html inside `<content>`.

If necessary, I can mass edit some things with notepad, like removing `type="html"`, to force it recognize inner divs as childs, but it is also something that I already tried. Unfortunately the content is treated like a simple text.

Comment: Your XPath expressions look correct, so I would guess the problem is in how you're using the plugin: what does `{expr}` do with the result of the XPath `expr`? What kinds of values (element nodes, attribute nodes, etc.) can it work with successfully?

Comment: I think there are no restrictions for values. But the bigger problem is that it is treating <content> as text. I have another tree with <author> and <name> as a child and it works perfectly. The image with what I have: [https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/143Y0j2r0X1h290a0X1D/Sem%20título.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the stuff that looks like HTML inside `<content>` isn't actually just text? The [tree view image you linked to](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/143Y0j2r0X1h290a0X1D/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo.jpg) suggests that it is just text: E.g. the `<` in `<div` is actually an escaped, literal `<`, not the beginning of a `<div` tag.

If you view the XML/HTML in a plain text editor, you will probably see `<content> &lt;div align=...`

In that case, `<content>` has no element children, just plain text. You can't select nodes like `img/@src` from it using XPath because it doesn't have any such nodes. You would have to find a way to parse it into XML or HTML, if you want to apply XPath to it.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly plain text. Maybe that's why it wasn't recognizing the tree. I tried to convert the content, but I got an invalid XML. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: Did you get an error saying it was **invalid** XML? or not well-formed XML? Because *invalid* implies a DTD or Schema, which doesn't seem to apply here. We could potentially help you with this problem, but you'll probably need to provide more information. E.g. show the code that's trying to parse the content, and show the exact error message you're receiving (and the exact content, if not the same as shown above, which does appear to be well-formed XML/HTML).

Answer (score 1):

The following do work using R and XML library. Just used `'//img/@src'`

```
library(XML)
html = '<content type="html">
  <div align="center" class="post-cover">
    <img src="IMG.jpg"/>
      <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      </ul>
      </div> 
      </content>'

doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
src = xpathSApply(doc, '//img/@src')
```

The output:

```
      src 
"IMG.jpg"
```